# Public double members vs. double& Accessors

Tags: c++, reference, private-members

I have some legacy code which I would like to modify. In class A I would like to add a few members (let's say 10) and allow access similarly to previous ones.

```
 class A
 {
 protected:
      double m_dmember1;
      double m_dmember2;
      double m_dmember3;

 public:
      double& Member1() { return m_dmember1; }
      double& Member2() { return m_dmember2; }
      double& Member3() { return m_dmember3; }

      A();
 }
```

So that's 10 more members and 10 more accessors. This looks redundant to me.

I don't know exactly why the previous developer used references to double for it's accessors. Looks like he wanted a way to access members with simple names only (similar behaviour to C# properties I guess).

So, should I simplify class A to this or is it a bad idea ?

```
 class A
 {
 public:
      double Member1;
      double Member2;
      double Member3;

      A();
 }
```

Instances of class A are then used in an Array, so maybe references are used to save memory ?

Answer (score 2):

From a design point of view, it's the same thing - they both break encapsulation.

Having accessors makes it easier to debug though, I'd leave the code as it is.

> I don't know exactly why the previous developer used references to double for it's accessors.

Because references will let you change the value of the member. He avoided making two methods (`get` and `set`) and made one instead.

> Instances of class A are then used in an Array, so maybe references are used to save memory ?

Nope, because the references are return types. They don't affect the memory footprint at all.

Comment: But by avoiding making two methods, he prevented you from accessing the members of a `const` object at all.

Comment: @MikeSeymour true, didn't say it was a fortunate choice :P